# Android: send post that has no response

Tags: java, android, http-post, apache-httpclient-4.x

In my app, I need to send all sorts of `POST` requests to a server. some of those requests have responses and others don't.

this is the code I'm using to send the requests:

```
private static final String TAG = "Server";
private static final String PATH = "http://10.0.0.2:8001/data_connection";
private static HttpResponse response = null;
private static StringEntity se = null;
private static HttpClient client;
private static HttpPost post = null;
public static String actionKey = null;

public static JSONObject sendRequest(JSONObject req) {
    try {
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        actionKey = req.getString("actionKey");
        se = new StringEntity(req.toString());
        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_ENCODING, "application/json"));
        se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
        post = new HttpPost(PATH);
        post.setEntity(se);

        Log.d(TAG, "http request is being sent");
        response = client.execute(post);
        Log.d(TAG, "http request was sent");

        if (response != null) {
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            String a = convertFromInputStream(in);
            in.close();
            return new JSONObject(a);
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "encoding request to String entity faild!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "executing the http POST didn't work");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "executing the http POST didn't work");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "no ActionKey");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private static String convertFromInputStream(InputStream in)
        throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    return (sb.toString());
}
```

---

This is the code for the `AsyncTask` class that sends the request:

```
class ServerRequest extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Void, JSONObject> {

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {
        JSONObject req = params[0];
        JSONObject response = Server.sendRequest(req);
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        // HANDLE RESULT
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

---

my problem starts when the server doesn't return a response. the `AsyncTask` thread stays open even after the work is done because the `HTTPClient` never closes the connection.

Is there a way to not wait for a response? this is something that will definitely add a lot of overhead to the server since all the Android apps trying to connect to it will keep the connection alive, and will probably cause many problems on the app itself.

Basically, what I'm looking for is a method that will allow me to send to `POST` message and kill the connection right after the sending of the request since there is no response coming my way.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. Why is there no response? Unless you are doing long polling, there should be some response, even it doesn't have a body, just a status code. How can you be sure the server even received your request, if you don't get/wait for a response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just, Set `ConnectionTimeOut` with HttpClient Object, (Code is for your understanding in your case it may be different)

```
int TIMEOUT_MILLISEC = 30000;  
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Now, It will terminate the Connection after **TimeoOut** you defined. But be sure this will throw `TimeOutException` so You have to handle this exception in your **HttpRequest**.. (Use Try -catch)

**EDIT:** Or you can use **HttpRequestExecutor** class.

From class [HttpRequestExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/protocol/HttpRequestExecutor.html#canResponseHaveBody%28org.apache.http.HttpRequest,%20org.apache.http.HttpResponse%29) of package [org.apache.http.protocol](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/protocol/package-summary.html)

```
protected boolean canResponseHaveBody (HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
```

Decide whether a response comes with an entity. The implementation in this class is based on RFC 2616. Unknown methods and response codes are supposed to indicate responses with an entity.
Derived executors can override this method to handle methods and response codes not specified in RFC 2616.